# Round a float up to the next integer in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, int

How can I round a float up to the next integer value in objective C?

```
1.1 -> 2
2.3 -> 3
3.4 -> 4
3.5 -> 4
3.6 -> 4
1.0000000001 -> 2
```

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You want the ceiling function. Used like so:

```
float roundedup = ceil(otherfloat);
```

Comment: That shows me not to trust the first documentation I read.  You are correct.

Comment: Take care to put a float in the function. ceil((width/100.) * 7.) works. ceil((width/100) * 7) not

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ceil()` function.

Someone did a little math in Objective C writeup here: http://webbuilders.wordpress.com/2009/04/01/objective-c-math/

Answer (score 2):

Just could not comment Davids answer. His second answer won't work as modulo doesn't work on floating-point values. Shouldn't it look like

```
if (originalFloat - (int)originalFloat > 0) {
    originalFloat += 1;
    round = (int)originalFloat;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Roundup StringFloat** remarks( ***this is not the best way to do it*** )
Language - **Swift & Objective C** | xCode - **9.1** 
What i did was convert string > float > ceil > int > Float > String 
String Float 10.8 -> 11.0
String Float 10.4 -> 10.0

**Swift**

```
var AmountToCash1 = "7350.81079101"
AmountToCash1 = "\(Float(Int(ceil(Float(AmountToCash1)!))))"
print(AmountToCash1) // 7351.0


var AmountToCash2 = "7350.41079101"
AmountToCash2 = "\(Float(Int(ceil(Float(AmountToCash2)!))))"
print(AmountToCash2) // 7350.0
```

**Objective C**

```
NSString *AmountToCash1 = @"7350.81079101";
AmountToCash1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",float(int(ceil(AmountToCash1.floatValue)))];
```

**OR** 
you can make a **custom function** like so
**Swift**

```
func roundupFloatString(value:String)->String{
  var result = ""
  result = "\(Float(Int(ceil(Float(value)!))))"
  return result
}
```

Called it like So

```
    AmountToCash = self.roundupFloatString(value: AmountToCash)
```

**Objective C**

```
-(NSString*)roundupFloatString:(NSString *)value{
    NSString *result = @"";
    result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",float(int(ceil(value.floatValue)))];
  return result;
}
```

Called it like So

```
    AmountToCash = [self roundupFloatString:AmountToCash];
```

Good Luck! and Welcome! Support My answer!