# Rounded up float value ios

Tags: objective-c

I Have a value for example `int value1 = 11` after dividing on 2 (`value1 / 2`) its returning 5. Real value in float is 5.5, can anybody help me to return 6 in this case, or another case..? In general, I want to round the value to the next higher..

Comment: Is ios in title really necessary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206291/round-a-float-up-to-the-next-integer-in-objective-c

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you *always* want to round up, and you have a `float` value, use `ceilf` (from the `<math.h>` library).

If you want to round up an integer division by `n`, do `(value + n-1) / n`. So, for a division by 2, this becomes `(value + 1) / 2`.

Answer (score 10):

there are functions ceil(<#(double)#>) or ceilf(<#(float)#>) which round value to higher

Also you should explicitly cast calculations to float/double to get value 5.5 which can be rounded to higher.

```
ceilf(value1 / 2.0f);
```

or

```
ceilf(1.0f * value1 / 2);
```

If you don't make this - it may be presented in next sequence:

```
ceilf(11/2) = 
1) 11/2 = result int = 5
2) ceilf(5)
3) 5 ->int implicitly cast to float -> 5.0f
4) result 5.0f
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, usually, you would just add 1:

int half = (value1+1)/2

so, you'll always round up. Should be the easiest way for integers.

Comment: That's a bad way to solve this problem without understand why it's rounded down. Might cause problems in the future when logic changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
ceil(value1 / 2)
```

Rounds up to the nearest int

Comment: it will not round up to nearest int. ceiling of that float value.

Comment: "ciel" is the French word for "sky". The function you're looking for is called "ceil".